# Issue with PlayN getting started tutorial

Tags: java, maven, playn

I am new to Java+Maven and PlayN. Please help me regarding following error.

Getting following error for playn-showcase project build:

> Failed to execute goal on project playn-showcase-java: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.googlecode.playn:playn-showcase-java:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find jlayer:mp3spi:jar:1.9.5 in https://ec2-ncisfb-build01.sng.ubi.com/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> 1?

Also when I compile and Run playn-showcase-html project, and browse it, on clicking any demo link, getting errors:

> (UnknownFileName?:-1) 2012-02-29 14:37:44,252 FATAL? Uncaught JavaScript? exception exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException? in , line 0

Ref : [code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted)

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me also after I deleted some files. You should have used git to download samples. So you can undelete showcase files via git:

"git ls-files -d | xargs git checkout --"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but in my case it was the fact that I had a mirror defined in my settings.xml for maven configurations.

The forplay-legacy repository was not accessible, jlayer:mp3spi is there referenced from the playn-project.

Worked fine after I removed the mirror. In your case looks like you have a cached version or something like that in your repository but is not getting the one from forplay-legacy.

```
<!--
 TEMP: obtain some artifacts from legacy forplay maven repository 
-->
<repository>
   <id>forplay-legacy</id>
   <url>http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
</repository>
```